# jquery.validate plugin accessing the form in ajax success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm confused on how to access the submitted form using the jQuery.validate plugin.

In the "success" option of the API options: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

it says that the 4th parameter in the success function is the jquery wrapped form object but my attempts to access it with jQuery keep saying its `undefined`.

here's how the success function looks on their examples page: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    var id=$form.attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
```

unfortunately, console.log says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined.`

any thoughts?

thanks,
tim

Comment: I think you're using jQuery < 1.4, because it has some note within `()`, see that

Comment: @thecodeparadox, thanks i'm using jQuery1.7.1. I saw that note but didn't know if i misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by explicitly writing out the jQuery form selector every time and not trying to pass it as an object.

So rather than trying to pass around `$form` I used this:

```
$('#myForm').attr(...)
```

It is more verbose but at least it works!

Answer (score 0):

the variable cannot start with `$` I suppose. Remove the `$` and try again?

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form)  {
    var id = form.attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
```

Or this might be another solution, if not a jQuery `object`:

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form)  {
    var id = $(form).attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
```

Other possibilities

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form)  {
    var id = $(form).attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, form)  {
    var id = form.attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { // Won't work
    var id = form.attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { // High chance
    var id = $($form).attr('id');
    console.log('id:'+id);
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: there can be more possibilities, `$()` wrapping and just prepending `$`. let us know if something solved. :)

Comment: can you put those possibilites in your answer? i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Yeah, added all possibilities I can think of. Might be the `$form` would not be a jQuery Object, so the last possibility does it. Try it and let us know. :)

Comment: thanks for trying but both `form` or `$form` are undefined. there is a more fundamental problem happening here

Comment: When you call the function `showResponse`, what is the syntax are you using? Are you filling up four fields with correct values?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12282/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-tim-peterson)

Comment: yes i'm doing exactly as the demo suggests. I've gotten everything to work normally. i'm actually going to bed now but if you wouldn't mind trying to figure it out i'll check SO in the morning. thanks!